# How to make generics and default value work together

Tags: typescript, function, generics

How can I modify this code to run

```
function say<T = boolean>(arg:T = false) {
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to
    if(arg) return ['hello']
    return 'hello'
}

const a = say() //type is string
const b = say(true) //type is string[]
```

Comment: is this what you wanted : `T extends boolean? string[] : string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) return type with [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYE9EB4AqiCmAHlPmACbKIBGccANvqkgLyLCp3L4B8AFAG4cQ+RK3acRqSjgCUiAN4BYAFCJEAJ3xQQ6pAKEiA-IgDaAcgAW+OnThmAuogBciS9dtm5UxHiIlylFDqwojGyEEwYADmJo4u4eqRUQDcKgC+Kipo6LwyyYgA9AUoEdFZGLziXHmFxQlJ5TlBwjVFJYnRsSpAA)

```ts
function say <T extends boolean = false>(value = false as T) {
  return (value ? ['hello'] : 'hello') as T extends true ? string[] : string;
}
```

Or an overloaded function signature, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=9&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYE9EAoBuqA2IApgPwBciwByRAlBclAE4xgDmA3ALABQoksBCgzY8hIhWbF6KZqzYBtALrc+4aPCRpMuAsUQBeStTqIA3r0SImRKCCZJd4xCUQKA5AAsi+fHHdKiBRePn7utIioyIjgANZgcADuYKoAvry82li0HIgA9HmyLOyZGFhU+DQ5+YWMxWyl6FhSdLkFRfLKvEA)

```ts
function say (value?: false): string;
function say (value: true): string[];
function say (value = false) {
  return (value ? ['hello'] : 'hello') as unknown;
}
```

In both cases, calling the function with `false` or implicit `undefined` will result in `string`, and calling with `true` will result in `string[]`:

```ts
say(); // string
say(false); // string
say(true); // string[]
```